# Angular 4 - Form status INVALID, but all fields form control status VALID

Tags: angular

I am doing an editing form. Ater binding the data that comes from the backend, the status of the form is invalid.  However, all fields are with valid status.  How can this be solved?

```js
createGerconForm(): FormGroup 
  {
    return this._fb.group({
      anexoGercon: new FormControl(),
      email: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      cpf: new FormControl('', [Validators.required,Validators.pattern(/\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\-\d{2}/i)]),
      origem: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      mes: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      ano: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      entradaCt:  new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      prazoDeAtendimento: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      numeroCT: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      responsavel: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    });
  }


bindFormGercon()
  {

    this.email.setValue(this.vm.item.emailRecebido,{onlySelf:true});

    this.name.setValue(this.vm.item.nomeParticipante,{onlySelf:true});


    this.cpf.setValue(this.maskToCPF(this.vm.item.cPF),{onlySelf:true});

    this.ano.setValue(this.vm.item.ano,{onlySelf:true});


    this.entradaCt.setValue(this._dateTimeSvc.covertToDateObject(this.vm.item.entradaCt),{onlySelf:true});


    this.prazoDeAtendimento.setValue(this._dateTimeSvc.covertToDateObject(this.vm.item.prazoAtendimento),{onlySelf:true});


    this.numeroCT.setValue(this.vm.item.numeroCT,{onlySelf:true});


    this.origem.setValue(this.vm.item.origem.id, {onlySelf:true});


    this.responsavel.setValue(this.vm.item.responsavel.id,{onlySelf:true});


    this.mes.setValue(this.vm.item.mes,{onlySelf:true});

  }
```

Debug status of fields:

```html
<p>Email: {{emailRecebido.status}}</p> 
<p>Name:  {{nomeParticipante.status}}</p> 
<p>Cpf:   {{cpf.status}}</p> 
<p>Origem: {{origem.status}}</p> 
<p>Mes:     {{mes.status}}</p> 
<p>Ano:    {{ano.status}}</p> 
<p>entradaCT:  {{entradaNoContencioso.status}}</p> 
<p>prazoDeAtendimento: {{prazoDeAtendimento.status}}</p>
<p>numeroCT: {{numeroCT.status}}</p>
<p>Responsavel: {{responsavel.status}}</p>
<p>Anexo:  {{anexoGercon.status}}</p>
<p>Form: {{gerconForm.status}}</p>
```

Result:

```
Email: VALID

Name: VALID

Cpf: VALID

Origem: VALID

Mes: VALID

Ano: VALID

entradaCT: VALID

prazoDeAtendimento: VALID

numeroCT: VALID

Responsavel: VALID

Anexo: VALID

Form: INVALID
```

Angular version: 4.2.4

Has anyone ever had this problem?  How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a duplicate of [Angular 4 button disabled even if the form has valid values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020816/angular-4-button-disabled-even-if-the-form-has-valid-values)

You can use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50021060/2724204) to easily debug your form.

The goal is to debug each form control (e.g. output it into your view) and find which stays invalid.

Comment: Really strange... Can you reproduce it on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) please?

Comment: Solved  when removing onlySelf property